# OssLicensesService.API is not available on this device

Tags: android, google-play-services, licensing

I'm using oss-license-plugin by google like in this [tutorial](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/blob/master/oss-licenses-plugin/README.md).

But when i opened OssLicensesMenuActivity, i got these warnings in LogCat:

unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.service.START on com.google.android.gms
Error getting license list from service: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: OssLicensesService.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}

and saw this
[screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DCdY.png)
[screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkSPK.png)

How can i resolve this problem?